# По какой причине при повторном построении дерева возникает ошибка доступа к памяти

Tags: delphi

Итак, задание состоит в построении прямого, обратного и симметричного обходов деревьев(бинарных). В моей реализации деревья строятся на динамических записях. В верхнее поле вводим дерево,например, из одного элемента 5 и нажимаем button1. Пробуем добавить еще 1 элемент после построения, например, 14(через запятую и без пробелов). Нажимаем на кнопку - ошибка. Ниже будет приведен необходимый кусок кода. Часть кода относится к рисованию этого дерева и никак пока что не задействована. Сразу после нажатия кнопки, предыдущее дерево очищается процедурой TreeClear. Строка элементов считывается в строку, а затем разбивается на массив "чисел", которые и передаются в addElem

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,
  System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ExtCtrls, Vcl.Grids, Vcl.ComCtrls,
  Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Button1: TButton;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Direct: TEdit;
    Reverse: TEdit;
    Symmetric: TEdit;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label3: TLabel;
    Image1: TImage;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

  Tree = ^TrElem;

  TrElem = record
    Left: Tree;
    Right: Tree;
    Value: Integer;
    Thread: Boolean;
    X, Y: Integer;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  TreeHead: Tree;
  CurrStrTree: ansistring;
  Deep:integer;
  left,right:integer;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure addElem(El: Integer; var Pointer: Tree);
begin
  if Pointer = nil then // Add leaf
  begin
    New(Pointer);
    Pointer^.Value := El;
    Pointer^.Left := nil;
    Pointer^.Right := nil;
    Pointer^.Thread := False;
    Pointer^.X:=400-(left*60)+(right*60);
    Pointer^.Y:=0+(deep*50);
  end
  else if El < Pointer^.Value then
  begin
    Inc(deep);
    Inc(Left);
    addElem(El, Pointer^.Left) // Less - to left
  end

  else
  begin
    Inc(deep);
    Inc(Right);
    addElem(El, Pointer^.Right) // Bigger - to right
  end;
end;

function directGo(El: Tree): ansistring;
begin
  if El = nil then
  begin
    Result := '0 ';
    Exit;
  end;

  Result := Result + '(' + IntToStr(El^.Value) + ')' + ' ';

  // Left subTree
  Result := Result + directGo(El^.Left);
  Result := Result + IntToStr(El^.Value) + ' ';

  // Right subTree
  Result := Result + directGo(El^.Right);
  Result := Result + IntToStr(El^.Value) + ' ';
end;

function reverseGo(El:Tree):ansistring;
begin
  if El = nil then
  begin
    Result := '0 ';
    Exit;
  end;

  Result := Result + IntToStr(El^.Value) + ' ';
  Result :=Result+reverseGo(El.Left);

  Result:=Result+IntToStr(El^.Value)+ ' ';
  Result :=Result+reverseGo(El.Right);

  Result := Result + '(' + IntToStr(El^.Value) + ')' + ' ';
end;

function symmetricGo(El:Tree):ansistring;
begin
  if El = nil then
  begin
    Result :='0 ';
    Exit;
  end;

  Result := Result + IntToStr(El^.Value) + ' ';
  Result :=Result+symmetricGo(El.Left);
  Result := Result + '(' + IntToStr(El^.Value) + ')' + ' ';

  Result :=Result+symmetricGo(El.Right);
  Result := Result + IntToStr(El^.Value) + ' ';

end;

procedure TreeClear(PointerHead: Tree);
begin
  if PointerHead = nil then
  begin

    Exit;
  end;
  TreeClear(PointerHead.Left);
  TreeClear(PointerHead.Right);
  Dispose(PointerHead);

end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
  arr: array of ansistring;
  Index: Integer;
begin
  Direct.Clear;
  Symmetric.Clear;
  Reverse.Clear;
  TreeClear(TreeHead);

  Index := 0;
  Setlength(arr, 1);
  CurrStrTree := Edit1.Text;
  for i := 1 to length(CurrStrTree) do
  begin
    if CurrStrTree[i] <> ',' then
    begin
      arr[Index] := arr[Index] + CurrStrTree[i];
    end
    else
    begin
      Inc(Index);
      Setlength(arr, index + 1);
    end;

  end;
  for i := 0 to length(arr) - 1 do
  begin
    deep:=0;
    left:=0;
    right:=0;
    addElem(StrToInt(arr[i]), TreeHead);
  end;
  Direct.Text := directGo(TreeHead);
  Reverse.Text  :=reverseGo(TreeHead);
  Symmetric.Text:=symmetricGo(TreeHead);

  //Form1.Image1.Canvas.Ellipse(TreeHead.X, TreeHead.Y, TreeHead.X+45,TreeHead.Y+45);

end;

end.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш код не умеет принимать 14, запишется 4. Используйте `TStringList.CommaText` для разделения строки.

Причина ошибки - вы считаете, что `Dispose` обнуляет указатель, а это не так, и при последующей проверке `if Pointer = nil` программа лезет куда попало.

Comment: Вы правы, но это еще не все. Обратите внимание, что в процедуре TreeClear параметр PointerHead является параметром-значением, следовательно для обнуления указателя потребовалось исправить и этот момент. Таким образом, добавляем PointerHead:=nil и исправляем формальный параметр на var @MBo

Comment: Угу, я в addElem обратил внимание, что с var сделано, а там не заметил